# sort by button descending & ascending

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
This button has three modes: First, Descending, Second Ascending Mode and Third Mode; No Sorting and I want to sort with jQuery.
```

```html
<div class="full-item">
 <div class="button-item">
  <button id="Sort-item">Sort by</button>
 </div>
 <div class="item-sort">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time" style="background: red;"><span>15:20</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```html
<body>

<style>
body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 auto;
 background: skyblue;
} 

.full-item{
 width: 800px;
 height: 600px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 background: grey;
}

.full-item .button-item{
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background: #B33771;

}

.full-item .button-item button{
 margin: 30px 45%;
}

.full-item .item-sort{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background: white;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.full-item .item-sort:first-child{
 margin-top: 10px;
}


.full-item .item-sort .item{
 width: 90%;
 height: 140px;
 background: red;
 /*padding: 10px;*/
 margin: 10px auto;
}

.item-sort .item .pic{
 width: 30%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #3B3B98;
 float: left;
}

.item-sort .item .time{
 width: 70%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #1B9CFC;
 float: right;
}

.item-sort .item .time span{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 line-height: 100px;
}


</style>

<div class="full-item">
 <div class="button-item">
  <button id="Sort-item">Sort by</button>
 </div>
 <div class="item-sort">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time" style="background: red;"><span>15:20</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
```

```js
 $("#Sort-item").click(function(){

  $(".item").sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($(a).find(".timeA")) > new Date($(b).find(".timeB"));
  }).each(function() {
    $(".item-sort").prepend(this);
  })

 });
```

```html
<body>

<style>
body{margin: 0 auto;padding: 0 auto;background: skyblue;} 
.full-item{width: 800px;height: 600px;margin: 50px auto;background: grey;}
.full-item .button-item{width: 100%;height: 80px;background: #B33771;}
.full-item .button-item button{margin: 30px 45%;}
.full-item .item-sort{width: 100%;height: 500px;background: white;margin-top: 10px;}
.full-item .item-sort:first-child{margin-top: 10px;}
.full-item .item-sort .item{width: 90%;height: 140px;background: red;margin: 10px auto;}
.item-sort .item .pic{width: 30%;height: 100%;background: #3B3B98;float: left;}
.item-sort .item .time{width: 70%;height: 100%;background: #1B9CFC;float: right;}
.item-sort .item .time span{color: white;text-align: center;display: block;line-height: 100px;}
</style>
<div class="full-item">
 <div class="button-item">
  <button id="Sort-item">Sort by</button>
 </div>
 <div class="item-sort">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What **specific** problem are you having with this code?

Comment: yep. thank for you

Comment: Please refrain from using code snippets everywhere in your question and only use them when necessary because they make it difficult to read your question and mess up its flow when they are all over the place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you divided your files as your question has many snippets and it's not clear where anything goes but you can find the way to do it in vanilla JS below (it's important to understand how vanilla JS handles this before jumping to JQuery).

I tried to stay as true as possible to your original CSS (despite thinking that it is a little bit inflated) and I merged the entire thing into a single document. Here goes:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 auto;
      background: skyblue;
    }

    .full-item {
      width: 800px;
      height: 600px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      background: grey;
    }

    .full-item .button-item {
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      background: #B33771;
    }

    .full-item .button-item button {
      margin: 30px 45%;
    }

    .full-item .item-sort {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      background: white;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .full-item .item-sort:first-child {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .full-item .item-sort .item {
      width: 90%;
      height: 140px;
      background: red;
      margin: 10px auto;
    }

    .item-sort .item .pic {
      width: 30%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #3B3B98;
      float: left;
    }

    .item-sort .item .time {
      width: 70%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #1B9CFC;
      float: right;
    }

    .item-sort .item .time span {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      line-height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="full-item">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="button-item">
        <button id="Sort-item-asc">Sort Asc</button>
      </div>
      <div class="button-item">
        <button id="Sort-item-desc">Sort Desc</button>
      </div>
      <div class="button-item">
        <button id="Sort-item-no">No Sort</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-sort">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="pic"></div>
        <div class="time"><span>15:20</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="pic"></div>
        <div class="time"><span>13:10</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="pic"></div>
        <div class="time"><span>18:40</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const buttonAsc = document.getElementById("Sort-item-asc")
    const buttonDesc = document.getElementById("Sort-item-desc")
    const buttonNo = document.getElementById("Sort-item-no")
    const times = document.getElementsByClassName("time")
    const originalHours = []
    for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      const hour = times[i].innerText;
      originalHours.push(hour)
    }
    buttonAsc.onclick = function () {
      let hours = []
      for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        const hour = times[i].innerText;
        hours.push(hour)
      }
      hours.sort()
      for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = hours[i];
      }
    }
    buttonDesc.onclick = function () {
      let hours = []
      for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        const hour = times[i].innerText;
        hours.push(hour)
      }
      hours.sort()
      hours.reverse()
      for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = hours[i];
      }
    }
    buttonNo.onclick = function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < originalHours.length; i++) {
        times[i].firstElementChild.innerText = originalHours[i];
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i want sort by through array.let FlyList = [{
    "time": "15:20",
  },
  {
    "time": "15:10",
  },
  {
    "time": "18:40",
  },
  {
    "time": "23:40",
  }
];